# iOS 9 : Add GMT Time Value

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I had search on google how to get GMT Time in Objective-C, and I got this :

```
+ (NSString *)GetGMTTime{
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm";

NSTimeZone *gmt = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:gmt];

return [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];}
```

Is there any way to add or set GMT Time ? (GMT+5)

Comment: you need GMT  + 5:30 or GMT+5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most flexible way is to use [`timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimeZone_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSTimeZone/timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:). This is more *typo proof* than using strings like *GMT+X*.

Here is a fuly working example:

```
+ (NSString *)GetGMTTime{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm";

    NSTimeZone *gmt = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:(60*60*5)];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:gmt];

    return [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

}
```

It returns *2016-08-29T12:13* (when GMT time is *2016-08-29T7:13*)

Note: `60*60*5` means `5 hours X 60 minutes X 60 seconds`

Answer (score 2):

Can try like this.

```
 NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT+5:30"];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you create `NSDate` instance then it will return date in `UTC or GMT` format by default.

Now when you convert this date to string by any date formatter then returned string (date) will be in local timezone (i.e. device's time zone).

You can create custom timezone with it's name to get date in that timezone.

```
  NSDate *date = [NSDate date]; //give current date in UTC or GMT
NSLog(@"current date in gmt : %@",date);

NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];

NSString *dateInStrFormat = [df stringFromDate:date];  // this date(string format) will be in current timezone that was set in your device and

NSLog(@"current date in local or device's default timezone : %@",dateInStrFormat);

NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"Asia/Kolkata"];

NSLog(@"timezone : %@",timeZone);

[df setTimeZone:timeZone];

NSString *dateInCustomTimeZone = [df stringFromDate:date]; // this will return date in Asia/Kolkata's timezone

NSLog(@"date in custom timezone : %@",dateInCustomTimeZone);
```

`NSLog(@"timezone : %@",timeZone);` will print something like, `Asia/Kolkata (IST) offset 19800`. `19800` is offset, if you divide it with `3600` then you will get difference with `gmt` like `(+/- 5.30 etc)`

[Link for different timezone names](http://pastebin.com/ibNU2RcG)

Or you can got timezone like,

```
  NSTimeZone *timezone1 = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT+5:30"];
NSLog(@"timezone : %@",timezone1);

NSTimeZone *timeAone2 = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:60*60*5.5];
NSLog(@"timezone : %@",timeAone2);
```